# Ubuntu, Apache, Railo pages never time out or load

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, railo

I'm part way through setting up a Railo server, running alongside Apache on a Ubuntu Rackpspace cloud server.

I've got Apache working fine, it will server PHP pages, I've got subdomains set up as well, that's all fine.

I've installed Railo, and I briefly got to look at the Railo administrator, but as soon as I added DirectorIndex index.cfm to the config files in /etc/apache/sites-available the Railo administrator stopped working, and all of my CFML domains just seem to load infinitely in the browser.

They never time out, and they never load. I don't understand what I've done wrong?

I've got an entry in my server.xml file like this:

```
    <Host name="dev.willshawmedia.com" appBase="webapps">
            <Context path="" docBase="/var/www/vhosts/willshawmedia.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/" />
    </Host>
```

And an file in /sites-available/ with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin pete@willshawmedia.com

    ServerName dev.willshawmedia.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/willshawmedia.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs
    DirectoryIndex index.cfm
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/willshawmedia.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've run a2ensite willshawmedia.com, and that's working becuase http://willshawmedia.com is displaying an old php page.

But I just can't get railo to work. Any ideas?

Have a look at http://dev.willshawmedia.com

EDIT: I've made some progress. I'm using the mod_jk connector, and the mod_jk.log file is saying tomcat is probably listening on the wrong port.

I'm also getting a service error=-3 for worker=ajp13_worker

Comment: How's Apache getting the request over to Tomcat?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that. When I installed Railo I think I opted the apache connector? Sorry, I'm not very good at this

Comment: It's using the mod_jk connector. I'll update the post